# Tomcat maxThread value dilemma

Tags: multithreading, apache, tomcat, multiprocessing

I am struck with a question and thus seeking your help.

The maxThread count value in tomcat controls the max number of concurrent request which a tomcat can serve(my understanding), which means max number of threads working.

Now suppose I set maxThread =2 and there are two threads working simultaneously currently. If one of the thread creates 2 child threads(calling some other api).

**My Question:** If maxThread=2 can 4 threads(two parent + 2 child) exists?
If yes what maxThread controls?
If not what will happen in such case?

Pardon if I am difficult to explain myself.

Answer (score 0):

For each HTTP request made on one of your `connector`, Tomcat creates one thread (the one named `http-8080-thread1` for instance).

The `maxThreads` value controls those threads. It is totally possible that several other threads exists or can be created in the JVM when `maxThreads` is reached.

Also, take into account there is an `acceptCount` which sets the number of requests queued when all requests threads are busy.

[More details in tomcat documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html#Standard_Implementation)

Comment: But we also should keep in mind differents between threads and connections. Count of connections not always equal to count of threads. Tomcat have two different modes - NIO and BIO.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24678661/tomcat-maxthreads-vs-maxconnections

Comment: @Cédric- Thank for the quick response. I am a little aware of the acceptCount and maxConnection params. All I want to cross verify if 'maxThreads' property controls the count of only Parent threads. I feel you are agreeing on it. Could you pls share some document favouring this.

I could not get this in the document.