# spring boot websocket broker set max connections

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-websocket

I have spring boot application using stomp over websocket.
I configured it as shown in the [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/websocket-spring).

I have many connections to the broker, and I saw that the limit is 10000. 
I checked that by trying to connect when there were 10000 connections and the connection was refused.

I searched for configuring the number of max connections but couldn't find anything about it.

Is there a way to set the max connections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot more searching, the problem was more general, connected to max-connections configured by the server, as shown [Spring-boot tomcat is able to offer only lesser than 10,000 connections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42219637/spring-boot-tomcat-is-able-to-offer-only-lesser-than-10-000-connections/42220767])