# How can I generate a 503 error by configuring tomcat?

Tags: rest, tomcat, configuration, tomcat8

I want to configure my **Apache Tomcat/8.5.37** by setting configuration attributes like *maxThreads*, *maxConnections*, *acceptCount* etc. in such a way, I can get 503 error in reply to a REST call by sending some concurrent requests (like 100 requests at a time).
How can to do that?

Edit: I am getting *'connection refused'* response in some cases. How can I get status 503 instead of *'connection refused'*?

Answer (score 1):

In `server.xml` file add following section

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           maxThreads="10"
           maxConnections="10"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443"
           maxPostSize="209715200" />
```

For more information [read this](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/http.html). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25765451/3708462) answer also may help

Comment: Tried with this configuration. 
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="2"
               redirectPort="8443" 
               maxThreads="5" 
               maxConnections = "10"
               acceptCount="11" />

Then called 50 requests simultaneously. But all are processed in batch of 5.

Comment: You can simulate by adding the java code `Thread.sleep(10 or 15 min)` in your jsp / servlet page, so that the requests are running continuously.

Comment: This is not an answer to the qustion. The question is how to response 503 instead of ECONNREFUSED.