# Tomcat maxThreads is config for acceptor threads or Request processing threads

Tags: tomcat, webserver

1. I follow [oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19146-01/821-1834/geeie/index.html) and wonder what is tomcat maxThreads config for?  acceptor threads or Request processing threads?
2. As oracle docs

> Request processing threads in a thread pool then pick up connections from the queue and service the requests.

[image]

What is pick up do: Does it pop() a connection in queue and process this or request processing thread only listening request from a connection in Connection queue?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tomcat - maxThreads vs maxConnections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24678661/tomcat-maxthreads-vs-maxconnections)

Comment: I suppose you are aware that Oracle iPlanet Web Server and Tomcat are two different products. Tomcat Coyote has always an acceptor thread and a request processing thread pool, but the details of the interactions between those two depend on the endpoint type (BIO (removed in 8.5), NIO, NIO2 or APR). Can you clarify which endpoint type are you interested in?

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz This is my mistake, I mean tomcat coyote nio , can you explain what happen when a request to tomcat server run a spring boot app, thank you

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the question [Tomcat - maxThreads vs maxConnections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24678661/tomcat-maxthreads-vs-maxconnections), the `maxThreads` attribute is the size of the [`Executor`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) used to process requests. No more than `maxThreads` requests will be processed at the same time.

On Tomcat 8.5 and later all connector types also use an acceptor thread, which just accepts up to `maxConnections` connections. Those connections that are beyond the limit remain in the operating system's queue (the `acceptCount` attribute is a hint for the OS on the preferred size of such a queue).

However the rest of Tomcat Coyote's architecture is obviously different from that of the Oracle iPlanet Web Server and depends on the connector type used.

You can read the details of the NIO connector in [this article](https://www.programmersought.com/article/80284949590/). Basically:

- the server reacts to network events by polling the sockets using [`Selector`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/channels/Selector.html)s. This way one thread can service all the client connections.
- there are only 3 threads dealing with the network I/O:

  1. the [`Acceptor`](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/9de2c402accda16824d0c2fd818d2f5d372ab404/java/org/apache/tomcat/util/net/Acceptor.java#L28), which only accepts new connections and sends them to the poller,
  2. the [`Poller`](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/main/java/org/apache/tomcat/util/net/NioEndpoint.java#L571), which responds to read/write events and dispatches them to the request executor,
  3. the [`BlockPoller`](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/37ae42a2996911b9ba6b88e7b0828f855b9d38f6/java/org/apache/tomcat/util/net/NioBlockingSelector.java#L236), which disappeared in version [9.0.47](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/changelog.html#Tomcat_9.0.47_(remm)) and dealt with blocking operations on the `ServletInputStream` and `ServletOutputStream`. The `Poller` took its tasks.
- there is no connection queue. The threads mentioned above just submit `Runnable` tasks to the executor. Internally the executor has a queue of `Runnable`s and each thread picks a task from there when it is free.